# Angular2 - Dynamically Updating Form Model

Tags: typescript, angular

I am working with `Angular2.beta15` and I have a form that I am attempting to mutate based on what a user selects from a select input.

So I am changing the `formModel (ControlGroup)` when an even fires with the following code:

```
public onActionChange(event: Event): void {
    this.jobAction = +(<HTMLSelectElement>event.srcElement).value;
    this._updateFormModel();
}
private _updateFormModel() {

    const optionals: string[] = ['jobPath', 'jobHost', 'password', 'username'];

    optionals.forEach( s => {
        this.log(`Setting null validator on ${s}`);
        this.formModel.controls[s].validator = Validators.nullValidator;
    });

    switch (this.jobAction ) {
        case 1: // email
            this.formModel.controls['username'].validator = Validators.required;
            break;
    }
}
```

The logic is that I'll hide the form fields that I don't need based on what the user selects from the drop down box.  This would preserve the values if the user selects a different item from the drop down box at a later time, but I would just remove all form validation with the `nullValidator` so the form will be valid.

Here is my components view:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <form [ngFormModel]="formModel" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="form-horizontal" novalidate>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div *ngIf="isAddOperation" class="panel-heading">Add a New Job</div>
            <div *ngIf="!isAddOperation" class="panel-heading">Modify Job</div>
            <div *ngIf="formModel && ! busy" class="panel-body">

                <global-error-message [isError]="isError" [message]="messageDescription"></global-error-message>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 control-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-9">
                        <input ngControl="name" type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Job Name" required autofocus />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
                        <error-message controlName="name"></error-message>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="description" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 control-label">Description</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-9">
                        <textarea ngControl="description" id="description" class="form-control" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
                        <error-message controlName="description"></error-message>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="query" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 control-label">Query</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-9">
                        <textarea ngControl="query" id="query" class="form-control" placeholder="select * from ..."></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
                        <error-message controlName="query"></error-message>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="dataSource" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 control-label">Data Source</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-9">
                         <select id="dataSource" class="form-control" ngControl="dataSource">
                            <option value="">=== Select One ===</option>
                            <option *ngFor="#d of dataSources" [value]="d.id">{{d.name}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
                        <error-message controlName="dataSource"></error-message>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="includeHeaders" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 control-label">Header Row</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-9">
                        <input id="includeHeaders" type="checkbox" ngControl="includeHeaders"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
                        <error-message controlName="includeHeaders"></error-message>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="publicJob" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 control-label">Public Job</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-9">
                        <input id="publicJob" type="checkbox" ngControl="publicJob"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
                        <error-message controlName="publicJob"></error-message>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="jobAction" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 control-label">Action</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-9">
                         <select controlName="jobAction" id="jobAction" (change)="onActionChange($event)" class="form-control"  >
                            <option value="0">No Action / Manual Execution</option>
                            <option value="1">Email</option>
                            <option value="2">FTP</option>
                            <option value="3">SFTP</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
                        <error-message controlName="jobAction"></error-message>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div *ngIf="jobAction == 1" class="form-group">
                    <label for="username" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 control-label">Recipient Email</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-9">
                         <input ngControl="username" type="text" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="email@domain.com"  />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
                        <error-message controlName="username"></error-message>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-offset-3  col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                    <input [disabled]="!formModel.valid" class="btn btn-primary" *ngIf="isAddOperation" value="Add" type="submit" />
                    <input [disabled]="!formModel.valid" class="btn btn-primary" *ngIf="!isAddOperation" value="Update" type="submit" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form> 
</div>
```

The problem I am hitting is I am getting:

```
angular2.dev.js:23925 EXCEPTION: Expression '!formModel.valid in JobEditComponent@151:31' has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true' in [!formModel.valid in JobEditComponent@151:31]BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23925BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ angular2.dev.js:23936ExceptionHandler.call @ angular2.dev.js:1320(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12857schedulerFn @ angular2.dev.js:13264SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Rx.js:10775SafeSubscriber.next @ Rx.js:10730Subscriber._next @ Rx.js:10690Subscriber.next @ Rx.js:10667Subject._finalNext @ Rx.js:11191Subject._next @ Rx.js:11183Subject.next @ Rx.js:11142EventEmitter.emit @ angular2.dev.js:13245NgZone._zoneImpl.ng_zone_impl_1.NgZoneImpl.onError @ angular2.dev.js:13666NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onHandleError @ angular2.dev.js:2143ZoneDelegate.handleError @ angular2-polyfills.js:394Zone.runGuarded @ angular2-polyfills.js:300NgZoneImpl.runInner @ angular2.dev.js:2155NgZone.run @ angular2.dev.js:13749(anonymous function) @ angular2.dev.js:12956schedulerFn @ angular2.dev.js:13264SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Rx.js:10775SafeSubscriber.next @ Rx.js:10730Subscriber._next @ Rx.js:10690Subscriber.next @ Rx.js:10667Subject._finalNext @ Rx.js:11191Subject._next @ Rx.js:11183Subject.next @ Rx.js:11142EventEmitter.emit @ angular2.dev.js:13245NgZone._checkStable @ angular2.dev.js:13689NgZone._zoneImpl.ng_zone_impl_1.NgZoneImpl.onLeave @ angular2.dev.js:13656NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke @ angular2.dev.js:2128ZoneDelegate.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:389Zone.runGuarded @ angular2-polyfills.js:297NgZoneImpl.runInner @ angular2.dev.js:2155NgZone.run @ angular2.dev.js:13749outsideHandler @ angular2.dev.js:13594ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:423Zone.runTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:320ZoneTask.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:490ListPicker._handleMouseUp @ about:blank:546
angular2.dev.js:23925 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Expression '!formModel.valid in JobEditComponent@151:31' has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'
```

So I am doing something that change detection doesn't like, but I am not sure exactly how to dynamically change a form from the component.  I know calling `enableProdMode()` would probably remove the error, but I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong.  Sorry, I'm new to Angular2!

** Update **

So I was able to get the form to work, but it seems clumsy, so I am still looking for a better way to implement forms where the model may change based on user responses.

Here is what I had to do:

```
 enableProdMode();  // so change detection wouldn't yell at me
```

Then in my Component I had to include/exclude the component, which I am not really sure what it really does, it seems like a duplication or special case for Validators.required.  Is there something I am missing, Am I doing something wrong that change detection is still complaining?

```
public onActionChange(event: Event): void {
    this.jobAction = +(<HTMLSelectElement>event.srcElement).value;
    this._updateFormModel();
}

private _updateFormModel() {

    const optionals: string[] = ['jobPath', 'jobHost', 'password', 'username'];

    optionals.forEach( s => {
        this.formModel.controls[s].validator = Validators.nullValidator;
        this.formModel.exclude(s);
    });

    switch (this.jobAction ) {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1: // email
            this.formModel.controls['username'].validator = Validators.required;
            this.formModel.include('username');         
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you shoud leverage the `ChangeDetectorRef` class and its `detectChanges` method instead of disabling the dev mode.

```
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private _cdr:ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  _updateFormModel() {
    (...)
    this._cdr.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked for dev mode, thanks!  Is there a better method to manage dynamic form components based on user input then what I am doing?

Comment: You're welcome! What do you exactly mean by dynamic form? Is the number of inputs fixed?

Comment: I come from a JSF world where when setting the rendered property to false validation isn't processed on the component, so I'm trying to figure the best way to exclude fields conditionally based on the input from a previous field. Is the best method to mutate the controlGroup and then make a call to this._cdr.detectChanges()? I am just looking to see if there is a more elegant solution to managing forms as I don't see many examples in the wild that something similar.  Thanks again!